# Xamarin: Window Returns Null, How to Get the Window?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, window

I am trying to get the window in Xamarin for Android, but the window is returning null.  The reason I would like to get the window is so I can apply a flag to remove the UI status bar.

I've already looked for a getWindow(java) equivalent method, but not found one.  I tried using this.Window in this example:

```
            var _winflag1 = WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;

            this.Window.AddFlags(_winflag1); // window is always null
```

That didn't work, so I also tried instantiation to no avail:

```
            var _winflag1 = WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;

            var _window = this.Window; //_window is always null

            _window.AddFlags(_winflag1);
```

I'd like to know a method I could use to get the current window in Xamarin.Android.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is inside MainActivity.cs.

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav/blob/FixLinkOverflow/MainActivity.cs

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that window variable has to be assigned inside MainActivity.cs OnCreate.

```
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{
   //it is very important to instantiate with static
   public static Window _window = null; // do this directly inside MainActivity

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

       //bunch of code here

      _window = this.Window; //we can only assign Window inside 
               //OnCreate??  I tried to do it in another custom method
                //but it would always return null
    }

    public void MyCustomWindowMethod()
    {
         //I was previously trying to assign window inside this method
         //that doesn't work.

         //this var hides the statusbar on android
         var _winflag1 = WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;

         //since we assigned window in OnCreate, now _window isn't null
         _window.AddFlags(_winflag1); 
    }
}
```